# WEC to LogRhythm

Tags: windows, logging, soc

I'm using a centralized server with the WEC in it in ordre to collect windows logs.
The hosts send their logs via Https 5986 to the server which will send it to LogRhythm DC.
My question is how to send logs forwarded by WEF to LogRhythm's DC, what tools to use?

After a reseach on google, I found that I can use NxLog, but I don't know how to perform.